# Stop Linux Clock to debug program that is time specific?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, analysis, clock

First, let me preface this by stating that this is based on a homework assignment.  As part of the assignment, I'm trying to examine/debug a program to determine what it does.  I found one part of the program that only reacts at 42 minutes past the hour.  I'd like to step through it with gdb to watch the assembly instructions and registers as it executes.  The thing is that I only have a one minute window to accomplish this.

Is there any way to "stop" the clock or trick the program into thinking that it is always x:42:00?

Thank you.

Jason

Comment: One hack solution is to write a script that resets the time on the system repeatedly until you stop it. You'd kick this off when you hit your breakpoint. Note: This is probably not the best solution.

Comment: Can't write this up properly at the moment, but try looking for `libfaketime`

Comment: I actually solved my own issue.  I ended up using the watch command with the date command.  It issues the date command, resetting the time every 2 seconds.